# Using the optimal learning rate results in random guessing accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am going through *Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow* by Aurélien Géron and I'm trying to make sense of what I'm doing wrong while solving an exercise. It's exercise 8 from Chapter 11. What I have to do is train a neural network with 20 hidden layers, 100 neurons each, with the activation function ELU and weight initializer He Normal on the CIFAR10 dataset (I know 20 hidden layers of 100 neurons is a lot, but that's the point of the exercise, so bear with me). I have to use Early Stopping and Nadam optimizer.

The problem that I have is that I didn't know what learning rate to use. In the solutions notebook, the author listed a bunch of learning rates that he tried and used the best one he found. I wasn't satisfied by this and I decided to try to find the best learning rate myself. So I used a technique that was recommended in the book: train the network for one epoch, exponentially increasing the learning rate at each iteration. Then plot the loss as a function of the learning rate, see where the loss hits its minumum, and choose a slightly smaller learning rate (since that's the upper bound).

This is the code from my model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[32, 32, 3]))
for _ in range(20):
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100,
                             activation="elu",
                             kernel_initializer="he_normal"))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr=1e-5)
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

(Ignore the value of the learning rate, it doesn't matter yet since I'm trying to find the right one.)

Here is the code that was used to find the optimal learning rate:

```
class ExponentialLearningRate(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, factor):
        self.factor = factor
        self.rates = []
        self.losses = []
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs):
        self.rates.append(keras.backend.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr))
        self.losses.append(logs["loss"])
        keras.backend.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, self.model.optimizer.lr * self.factor)

def find_learning_rate(model, X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=32, min_rate=10**-5, max_rate=10):
    init_weights = model.get_weights()
    init_lr = keras.backend.get_value(model.optimizer.lr)
    iterations = len(X) // batch_size * epochs
    factor = np.exp(np.log(max_rate / min_rate) / iterations)
    keras.backend.set_value(model.optimizer.lr, min_rate)
    exp_lr = ExponentialLearningRate(factor)
    history = model.fit(X, y, epochs = epochs, batch_size = batch_size, callbacks = [exp_lr])
    keras.backend.set_value(model.optimizer.lr, init_lr)
    model.set_weights(init_weights)
    return exp_lr.rates, exp_lr.losses

def plot_lr_vs_losses(rates, losses):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.plot(rates, losses)
    plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
    plt.hlines(min(losses), min(rates), max(rates))
    plt.axis([min(rates), max(rates), min(losses), losses[0] + min(losses) / 2])
    plt.xlabel("Learning rate")
    plt.ylabel("Loss")
```

The `find_learning_rate()` function exponentially increases the learning rate at each iteration, going from the minimum learning rate of 10^(-5) to the maximum learning rate of 10. After that, I plotted the curve using the `function plot_lr_vs_losses()` and this is what I got:

[image]

Looks like using a learning rate of `1e-2` would be great, right? But when I re-compile the model, with a learning rate of `1e-2` the model's accuracy on both the training set and the validation set is about 10%, which is like choosing randomly, since we have 10 classes. I used early stopping, so I can't say that I let the model train for too many epochs (I used 100). But even during training, the model doesn't learn anything, the accuracy of both the training set and the validation set is always at around 10%.

This whole problem disappears when I use a much smaller learning rate (the one used by the author in the solutions notebook). When I use a learning rate of `5e-5` the model is learning and reaches around 50% accuracy on the validation set (which is what the exercise expects, that's the same accuracy the author got). But how is it that using the learning rate indicated by the plot is so bad? I read a little bit on the internet and this method of exponentially increasing the learning rate seems to be used by many people, so I really don't understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a heuristic search method on an unknown exploration space.  Without more information on the model/data characteristics, it's hard to say what went wrong.

My first worry is the abrupt rise to effective infinity for the loss; you have an edge in yoru exploration space that is *not* smooth, suggesting that the larger space (including many epochs of training) has a highly irruptive boundary.  It's possible that any learning rate near the epoch-=1 boundary will stumble across the cliff at later epochs, leaving you with random classifications.

The heuristic you used is based on a couple of assumptions.

- Convergence speed as a function of learning rate is relatively smooth
- Final accuracy is virtually independent of the learning rate.
  It appears that your model does not exhibit these characteristics.

The heuristic trains on only one epoch; how many epochs does it take to *converge* the model at various learning rates?  If the learning rate is too large, the model may do that final convergence very slowly, as it circles the optimum point.  It's also possible that you never got close to that point with a rate that was too large.

Without mapping the convergence space with respect to that epoch-1 test, we can't properly analyze the problem.  However, you *can* try a related experiment: starting at, perhaps, 10^-4, fully train your model (detect convergence and stop).  Repeat, multiplying the LR by 3 each time.  When you cross into non-convergence around .0081, you have a feeling for where you no longer converge.

Now subdivide that range [.0027, .0081] as you see fit.  Once you find an upper endpoint that *does* converge, you can use that to guide a final search for the optimal learning rate.

Comment: So how about this approach (I'm thinking generally, for future problems as well): I try this approach of exponentially increasing the learning rate in the span of maybe 3-5 epochs (I won't use just 1 epoch like I did here), and then plot the loss as a function of the learning rate. If I see anything suspicious (like an abrupt rise of the loss to infinity, or like the fact that the model is NOT converging), I start trying various learning rates, from small to big and train on just maybe 10-20 epochs. Then I use the one that got the best accuracy on the validation set. What about this?

Comment: Speculation on how well that might work is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  The approach is a sound one for some experimentation spaces.  Without knowing a *lot* more about the model and data, we have no way to predict.  I could state conditions under which this would be a very good or very bad approach, but doing so is, again, too broad for this forum.

Comment: I understand. But could you please point me in the right direction towards learning this stuff? How to pick the right learning rate and everything related to it? Is there any source you could maybe recommend for me? Thanks a lot for taking the time!

Comment: (1) Asking for such sources is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  (2) No, this is not something that comes in a single source.  This is "background art" that you learn in general and learn to apply to your specific situation.